# why am i getting: Plugin name "simplePropelFeedPlugin.tgz" is not a valid package name?

Tags: php, symfony1

i am following the tutorial:

```
http://jasonswett.net/blog/how-to-write-a-symfony-plugin/
```

and when i run:

```
./symfony plugin:install simplePropelFeedPlugin.tgz
```

i get the error?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tgz file is a gzipped (compressed) tar archive (bundle of files combined into one).

You need to decompress and extract that archive to a folder, and put it in the plugins subdirectory of your project.

Then you can install the plugin using the plugin's name, not the filename of the zipped archive you downloaded.